# Get file name of url when url ends with "/"

Tags: c#, file, url, default

I am wondering how to get the file name of an internet url that doesn't contain the file name.

For example "http://www.google.com/". How do I get the "index.html"?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is a little more tricky then you think. What if the default document is **not** `index.html`? Only the server knows for sure! Better yet... how do you know it even represents a file? It's just a URI after all...

Comment: You can't be sure that the page you are receiving is a physical file. Actually, nowadays, most of the resources browsers receives are *logical* rather than *physical*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that as explained by two comments to the question

1. the file itself can be index.htm, index.html,index.php, index.asp or any other. You do not know what really the file is.
2. If the website is using a framework, the file may not be an existing file but a redirect to a completely different file name as pointed out to @andrecalil.

One way you can do it put all this *possible* files names in an array and use a function like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (PHP function) to see if returns any contents. If it does, that mean that file name is used, otherwise, that particular file is not use. For sites like WordPress, this approach may not work because they do not use physical files. They use redirect (I believe).

This is just a one possible approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
string fileNameILike = "index.html"
```

If there is no file name segment of Url than there is no file name you can get from the Url - just invent one if you have to (i.e. for saving files on client). Most server framework does not even have physical file backing particular urls.

Comment: If I know the MIME type, can I logically use that for more accurate guessing?

Comment: Not really... I could have `something.com/myfile.jpg` return something that is not `image/jpeg`, so the extension does not guarantee the file type and vice versa. Why do you need to know then filename?